# setRightSideTexture method in Sweethome3D API

Tags: java, sweethome3d

I am using [Sweethome3d](http://www.sweethome3d.com/javadoc/) in order to create a house. This is the API of SH3D. I want to use the Wall Class and especially this method:

```
setRightSideTexture(HomeTexture rightSideTexture) 
      Sets the right side texture of this wall.
```

The problem is that I cannot understand what is HomeTexture.

Can anybody give me an example?
I want to use the `library of textures` that already exists in SH3D.

Answer (score 0):

[`HomeTexture`](http://www.sweethome3d.com/javadoc/com/eteks/sweethome3d/model/HomeTexture.html), defined in their docs is:

> An image used as texture on home 3D objects.

Its constructor take a `TextureImage` object.

Comment: But If I want to use the names of the textures that I already exist in the library of SweetHome3D? It's difficult for me to understand how to use this.

Comment: Could you give me an example if it's possible.